# How calculate the cartan matrix of the twisted quantum affine algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups

the cartan matrix of the type $A_{2}^{(2)}$, $A_{2r-1}^{(2)}$, $A_{2r-1}^{(2)}$, $D_{r+1}^{(2)}$, $E_{6}^{(2)}$. I know the cartan matrix of the type $A_{2}^{(2)}$ is
\begin{align} 
 \left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
     2 & -4 \\
    -1 & 2 \\
   \end{array}
 \right)
\end{align}.
But I don't know how calculate the cartan matrix of the rest types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cartan matrices of these types are computed, among other references, in 
the book [Affine Lie Algebras, Weight Multiplicities, and Branching Rules](https://books.google.at/books?id=dEPg77gKopoC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=Cartan+matrices+of+one-parameter+twisted+quantum+affine+algebras&source=bl&ots=bKNbx7jM9-&sig=CFJ3JfJ9POa8DjW--JE6MMyGqSo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNrqG7idnLAhVFKg4KHciQAyIQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Remark: For the two-parameter case see
the article [Two-parameter twisted quantum affine algebras](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00090) on page $4$.

Comment: Thank you very much.I found this paper too,but I don't understand the difference between one parameter and two parameter, can you give me an example?

Comment: I edited the answer for the one-parameter case.